# kitti dataset for object detection and classification 3D lidar point cloud data

Tags: dataset, cluster-analysis, object-detection, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I am doing a project on object detection and classification in Point cloud data.For this, I require point cloud dataset which shows the road with obstacles (pedestrians, cars, cycles) on it.I explored the Kitti website, the dataset present in it is very sparse. I cannot understand if there is a point cloud (.pcd) file present on the kitti website, which can serve my purpose, or do I need to convert the any kitti dataset to point cloud format.If yes, then how?
I saw  a link on the kitti website with the velodyne point cloud data:
http://www.cvlibs.net/download.php?file=data_object_velodyne.zip

I have sent the request for the download link of it, but haven't received it.

Any help/suggestion in this regard would be deeply appreciated .

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That link gives data in bin format. Check the spam folder, mine was in the spam folder. You may have to reshape it to proper shape to read it. Let me know once you download that data.